# If $a+b+c=ab+ac+bc$ so $\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}+\frac{15}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\geq8$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers such that $a+b+c=ab+ac+bc$. Prove that:
>   $$\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}+\frac{15}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\geq8$$

I tried BW:

Let $a=\min\{a,b,c\}$, $b=a+u$ and $c=a+v$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}+\frac{15(ab+ac+bc)^3}{(a+b+c)^3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}\geq\frac{8(ab+ac+bc)}{a+b+c}$$ or
$$9(u^2-uv+v^2)a^7-3(2u^3+27u^2v-54uv^2+2v^3)a^6+$$
$$+(76u^4-413u^3v+489u^2v^2+73uv^3+76v^4)a^5+$$
$$+(131u^5-367u^4v+185u^3v^2+482u^2v^3+92uv^4+131v^5)a^4+$$
$$+(69u^6-71u^5v-115u^4v^2+434u^3v^3+173u^2v^4+181uv^5+69v^6)a^3+$$
$$+(14u^7+14u^6v-49u^5v^2+109u^4v^3+163u^3v^4+86u^2v^5+95uv^6+14v^7)a^2+$$
$$+(u^8+3u^7v-u^6v^2+9u^5v^3+43u^4v^4+31u^3v^5+31u^2v^6+17uv^7+v^8)a+$$
$$+uv^3(u+v)^3(u^2+v^2)\geq0$$
and there are problems with $-3(2u^3+27u^2v-54uv^2+2v^3)$

and with $76u^4-413u^3v+489u^2v^2+73uv^3+76v^4$.

Thank you!

Comment: Can we use Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: @Shrey Aryan Yes, of course, but what happens with the system, which you'll get?

Comment: If I may ask, where do you find so many of these interesting inequalities?

Comment: @anonymaker000010001 I just like to prove inequalities and I wrote all inequalities, which I don't know to prove. By the way, what do you think about following inequality? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170649/

Answer (score 0):

This sort of inequality can be routinely proved with [Cylindrical Decomposition](https://www3.risc.jku.at/publications/download/risc_4231/s65kauers.pdf) on computers.

Substitute by $a=x, b=x+y, c=x+z$, the inequality is to show that
$$
f(x,y,z) \ge 0
$$
where $f(x,y,z)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients of degree $9$.
Then a Cylindrical Decomposition shows that the inequality is true when $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$ and $z \ge 0$.

Mathematica code for this proof is as the follows:

```
ieq1 = a^2/b + b^2/c + c^2/a + (
  15 (a*b + a*c + b*c)^3)/((a + b + c)^3 (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)) >= 
  (8 (a*b + a*c + b*c))/(a + b + c);

f1[a_, b_, c_] = ieq1[[1]] - ieq1[[2]] // Together // Numerator // Simplify;

assume1 = x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0;

f2[x_, y_, z_] =  f1[x, x + y, x + z] // Expand // Simplify[#, assume1] &;

ieq3 = ForAll[{x, y, z}, assume1, f2[x, y, z] >= 0];

CylindricalDecomposition[ieq3, {}]
```

The output is `True`.

Note this might take a while to finish, depending on how good your computer is.

Answer (score 0):

From @Michael Rozenberg's result, it suffices to prove that
\begin{align}
&9(u^2-uv+v^2)a^7-3(2u^3+27u^2v-54uv^2+2v^3)a^6\\
&\quad +(76u^4-413u^3v+489u^2v^2+73uv^3+76v^4)a^5\\
&\quad +(131u^5-367u^4v+185u^3v^2+482u^2v^3+92uv^4+131v^5)a^4 \ge 0.
\end{align}
Due to homogeneity, assume that $a=1$. It suffices to prove that
\begin{align}
&92 u v^4+131 v^5+12 v^4+(8 v^2-v)^2 \\
&\quad + (482 u^2+73 u+10) v^3+(185 u^3+489 u^2+162 u+8) v^2\\
&\quad + (-367 u^4-413 u^3-81 u^2-9 u) v+131 u^5+76 u^4-6 u^3+9 u^2
\ge 0.
\end{align}
It suffices to prove that
\begin{align}
&(482 u^2+73 u+10) v^3+(185 u^3+489 u^2+162 u+8) v^2\\
&\quad + (-367 u^4-413 u^3-81 u^2-9 u) v+131 u^5+76 u^4-6 u^3+9 u^2
\ge 0. \tag{1}
\end{align}
There are several proofs for this. Here is one of them.
Let
\begin{align}
f(v) &= (482 u^2+73 u+10) v^3+(185 u^3+489 u^2+162 u+8) v^2 \\
&\quad + (-367 u^4-413 u^3-81 u^2-9 u) v+131 u^5+76 u^4-6 u^3+9 u^2.
\end{align}
If $u=0$, clearly it holds that $f(v)\ge 0$. In the following, assume that $u > 0$. The discriminant of $f(v)$ is
\begin{align}
&\mathrm{discr}(f) = -u^2\left(88218434659 u^{12}+162085007214 u^{11}+117371439295 u^{10}\right.\\
&\left. +45609510660 u^9 + 5959866068 u^8-593665360 u^7+3161956460 u^6\right.\\
& \left. +2728254872 u^5+1146782456 u^4+226910860 u^3+21433556 u^2+891672 u+13248\right).
\end{align}
Since $5959866068 u^8-593665360 u^7+3161956460 u^6\ge 0$, we have $\mathrm{discr}(f) < 0$. Thus, the equation $f(v)=0$ has only one real root on $(-\infty, \infty)$.
Note also that $f(0) = 131 u^5+76 u^4-6 u^3+9 u^2 > 0$. Thus, the only one real root of $f(v)=0$ on $(-\infty, \infty)$ is negative. Thus, $f(v) \ge 0$ for $v \ge 0$. We are done.