An inequality supposedly using Titu's Lemma aka Sedrakayan's Inequality
If $$(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$$ and $$a+b+c=ab+bc+ac,$$ how do you prove that $$\frac{a^{2}}{b}+\frac{b^{2}}{c}+\frac{c^{2}}{a}+\frac{3}{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}\geq4?$$
Apparently, this inequality involves using the Titu-Andreescu inequality, or Sedrakyan's inequality. I first tried directly applying the inequality onto the first part of the LHS, which yielded $$\frac{a^{2}}{b}+\frac{b^{2}}{c}+\frac{c^{2}}{a}+\frac{3}{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^{2}}{a+b+c}+\frac{3}{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}=a+b+c+\frac{3}{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}$$. I then felt like I was neglecting the piece of information that $$a+b+c=ab+bc+ac,$$ and thought that the identity $$(a+b+c)^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+2(ab+bc+ac)$$ might help out. But I really don't see how you could apply something like this here, however I feel like I'm missing something and I feel really close to the solution. Is there a way to do this without any techniques from multivariable calculus, especially with the Titu-Andreescu Inequality? Any help would be appreciated.

This is similar, so you may want to read:  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h496432p2787766 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173135/

I think using this form of C-S turns the inequality more complicated. Maybe try to write a homogenous expression out of the inequality.
