# Inequality with one variable

Tags: real-analysis

Hello I have a problem with an inequality  :

let $x$ a positive real number we have :

$0\geq -[\cos(\arctan((7x)^{\frac{1}{2}}))^{\frac{2}{3}}+ \cos(\arctan((\frac{7}{x})^{\frac{1}{2}})))^{\frac{2}{3}}] + \cos(\arctan(\sqrt{3x})) + \cos(\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{3}{x}}))$

I have a no idea to prove that properly .

Edit : At the beginning I want to prove this inequality from this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170649/prove-that-sqrt3-fracaa7b-sqrt3-fracbb7a-geq-sqrt-fraca)

So my idea was to use trigonometric identites like this :

$\cos(\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{3a}{b}}))=\sqrt{\frac{b}{3a+b}}$

And

$\cos(\arctan((\frac{7a}{b})^{\frac{1}{2}}))^{\frac{2}{3}}=(\frac{b}{7a+b})^{\frac{1}{3}}$

My second idea is to make the classical substitution :

$a=bx$

And now it gives the inequality you have above .

To prove that I think we can use [this](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/274_05_JIPAM/274_05_www.pdf) and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0753)

Thanks

Comment: I think you're missing a closing bracket somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\cos \left(\arctan \sqrt{3x}\right)+\cos \left(\arctan \sqrt{3/x}\right)-\cos \left(\arctan \sqrt{7x}\right)^{2/3}-\cos \left(\arctan \sqrt{7/x}\right)^{2/3} \\ = \frac{1}{(3x+1)^{1/2}}+\frac{1}{(3/x+1)^{1/2}}-\frac{1}{\left(7x+1\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}-\frac{1}{\left(7/x+1\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$
Just note that $\cos(\arctan(f)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{f^2+1}}$